# Strange Parcelable implementation

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

My code for saving instance in bundle is working but I don't understand how it is working.

Student's name after clicking on button saving in bundle if I rotate device.

Here is my class

```
package com.example.app;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Student implements Parcelable {

   private String firstName;

   private String lastName;


   public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public String getDisplayedName()
   {
       return lastName + " " + firstName;
   }

   @Override
   public int describeContents() {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

   }
}
```

You can see here that I don't write any code in method writeToParcel and don't create CREATOR field in class.
However it is working on all my devices include emulator device

Here is my activity code

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Student student;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button generateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generate);
    generateButton.setOnClickListener(generateStudentName);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        student = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("student");
        writeStudent();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelable("student", student);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void writeStudent() {
    final TextView studentName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.student_name);
    studentName.setText(student.getDisplayedName());
}

private View.OnClickListener generateStudentName = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        student = new Student(String.valueOf(randomGenerator.nextInt(10000)), String.valueOf(randomGenerator.nextInt(10000)));
        writeStudent();
    }
};


}
```

Why it happens?

Comment: The student name appear before you click your generateButton or after?

Comment: Student's name after clicking on button is saved in bundle if I rotate device and show again

Comment: but is also referenced as local variable, I think your code just work because of that...

Comment: See the reference http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html
our activity will be destroyed and recreated each time the user rotates the screen. When the screen changes orientation, the system destroys and recreates the foreground activity because the screen configuration has changed and your activity might need to load alternative resources (such as the layout).

Comment: So you can test local variable will be null

Comment: Wow, this is very strange, I just searched for information about auto parcable items when working only with String's but I didn't find nothing...